# My own camera activity

Tags: android, camera

I want to create funny app with camera,(something like [THIS](http://www.myhuntingnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/sniper-game.jpg) but more simple with real enviroment from camera) but before I will start I have few questions:

If it is possible to use camera but dont open deafult [CAMERA](http://postimg.org/image/v5ulboxgp/).

I want to add my own buttons there and change camera aim for something like SNIPER´s aim.

Is it possible or not ??If yes how? I have found only how to open deafult camera and take picture, nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible or not ?

Programmers can do this, yes.

> If yes how? I have found only how to open deafult camera and take picture, nothing else.

Use `android.hardware.Camera`, as is described in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera).